# Weight Paint options changing from active group to all groups

Tags: vertex-groups

I'm using Blender 3.5.0.

I was working on one of my projects when I realized that if I tried to invert the weight paint from one of the vertex groups it would invert all the other groups in the mesh as well.
I noticed that when I first open blender the invert option will show: 'Invert active vertex group's weights: Active Group, The active Vertex Group'. But when I take the cursor alway from the invert button and then go back it shows: 'Invert active vertex group's weights: All Groups, All Vertex Groups'. It happens with all the other options too.
I tried other projects and this happens as well. I tried to reinstall blender but to no avail.
The only thing that seems to fix it is to use an older version before 3.4.
I'm out of ideas and would really appreciate it if you could help me.
Thanks.